# When tap outside the side menu, menu should menu should go in as well as action perform in view controller where user tapped

Tags: iphone, ios7

I am working in an iPad application. I have an left side menu in my app. I want to implement a feature. suppose our left menu is in open mode and i have tapped out side the left navigation. My menu is currently hiding but my viewcontroller is not taking tap action where i have tapped. I am using John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController library (https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) for side menu.

Answer (score 0):

Vinay i haven't check that library which you are using, but I am sure that when you open that left side menu there will be virtual button or tap gesture adding on right side. So ultimately you are not clicking on you right side controller (when you tap on right side while left menu is open). (FYI: This is just like popoverview behaviour, If click outside of that view view will automatically closed. )

If you want to detect where user tap, you need to modify that library. Add tap gesture on your right side view and use one BOOL flag to maintain state of Left menu (open/close). Depending on that you can perform your desire action. Hope this will help you.